# How to make a bool variable return as 0 or 1 instead of true or False in c++?

Tags: c++, boolean

i am using a bool variable in a piece of code. When i try to access that variable from a another routine, i am reading the value as "True" or "False". Since i am directly displaying to a UI interface, i want to read that variable as 0 or 1. How can do it?

Comment: Ehh, Why don't you show `true` as `1` and `false` as `0` if that what you want?  Not really sure what you are asking here..

Comment: Why not `static_cast<int>(myBool);`?

Comment: Can you show us your code? How exactly a `bool` gets converted to a string depends on what you use to convert it. The standard IO streams would print it as `1`/`0` by default, rather than `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a `bool` type to an `int` type then this is a good use for the unary plus operator:

```
bool b;
+b; // This is an `int` type
```

The proof:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
    bool b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<int, decltype(b)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<int, decltype(+b)>::value;
}
```